# SSRS Merge Data Across 2 Group Values

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs

I have created a report for SSRS 2008 which produces the results below.

[image: Result from report:]
What I am looking to achieve is for those results in pink, AD, to be under both AM and PM with the text centered i.e. merged cells.

The weekdays and AM/PM are group headings in a matrix based on fields in my table. To display the data I am using a table within the data region of a matrix.

I've read other posts about creating an additional row in the table which has 2 cells merged together, using an expression to hide this row when it is not used though I've not managed to get this to work correctly.

**UPDATE 28/03/2012:**
I've managed to get the AD to appear under both AM and PM. What I did was remove the AM/PM column group and create 2 cells under the Weekdays group and input the text AM and PM in these cells. I then created 2 rows in the data section of the matrix with the bottom row having 2 columns. In each of these cells there is a table with the expression

=IIF(Fields!SessionIdentifier.Value="AD","AD",Nothing)

and the row visibility in each table is set using an expression:

=IIF(Fields!SessionIdentifier.Value="AD", False, True)

What I would like to do now is hide the top row in the data region of the matrix when it is empty but I haven't figured out the expression to do this.
[image]

Comment: For future reference, changing the question to this degree is probably when you should have started another question (and linked back to this question, indicating that you are building off of that.) I've deleted my earlier answer, since it no longer matched the question.

Comment: OK thanks, I wasn't aware of linking questions like this.

Comment: I've managed to hide the row where AD would appear when the entire row is empty, though I've not been able to hide the row where it is empty on individual days (e.g. Thursday, DT1). For the time being I am creating duplicate records using a UNION ALL query. I think that what I am trying to achieve is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit kludgey, but here's an idea sketch... instead of merging the cells, could you fake it by placing an A in the left cell aligned to the right and a D in the right cell aligned to the left?  You could then use expressions to control value, alignment, color, and borders of the two separate cells.

Let me know if you need more details.  I think this would give you the visual you want.  Good luck!